# Powers of $x$ which are always positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've learnt that the square of any real number is always positive. So, we know $x^2\ge0$ for any real number $x$. Similarly, $x^{2k}\ge0$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$ and $k\in\mathbb N$. How can we find all of the forms of $r$ for which $x^r$ is positive if it is real too?

Comment: Among the integer exponents, you've found them all (apart from $0$).

Comment: if r mod 2 = 0 , then it will be positive

Comment: I know, but the exponent shouldn't be necessarily an integer.

Comment: If $x<0$, then $x^{k}$ is positive when $k$ is an even integer, negative when $k$ is an odd integer, and no longer real when $k$ is not an integer.

Comment: @mjqxxxx But what about $(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$?

Answer (score 0):

if x>0 
than r can be Any real number

if x<0  than 
 Some of the systems are giving -1 and some of them are giving 1 for (-1)^(2/3)
 so it is ambiguous to give answer if You can clear than answer can be find out .
 You can check it on 
 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%5E%282%2F3%29&lk=4&num=2&lk=4&num=2
 http://ideone.com/Mm3n9s

Comment: No i think we can find all of the forms, as our teacher said too. + Please note that i want it to be positive IF REAL for all $x$.