# What is wrong with the reasoning in $(-1)^ \frac{2}{4} = \sqrt[4]{(-1)^2} = \sqrt[4]{1} = 1$ and $(-1)^ \frac{2}{4} = (-1)^ \frac{1}{2} = i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, radicals

$$(-1)^ \frac{2}{4} = \sqrt[4]{(-1)^2} = \sqrt[4]{1} = 1$$

$$(-1)^ \frac{2}{4} = (-1)^ \frac{1}{2} = i$$

Came across an interesting Y11 question that made pose this one to my self. I can't for the life of me, find the flaw in the initial reasoning.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/317546/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608050/96384

Comment: Upshot: For the life of you, don't expect any well-behaved exponentiation / power rules when the base is a negative number.

Comment: [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2085631/21820), and note the [comment by Lubin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085268/does-i4-equal-1/2085631#comment4285832_2085631).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is essentially the same as asking what's wrong with:

$1=\sqrt{(1)^2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=-1$.

The error stems from being ambiguous about the meaning of $\sqrt{x}$ or, more generally, of $\sqrt[p]{x}$. A (real or) complex number $x\neq 0$ has a **set** of $p$ complex $p^{th}$ roots. If $x$ is a positive real number, exactly one of those roots is going to be a positive real number, so in some contexts (mostly when one is considering only positive real numbers), one talks about that single positive real root as **the** $p^{th}$ root of $x$, ignoring the other roots.

But you have to be consistent. You can't say "look, $-2$ is **a** square root of $4$, but **the** square root of $4$ is $2$, so $-2=2$".

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers are not addressing the real issue, and hence are in my opinion misleading. The problem has nothing to do with multiple roots.

When you write "$a^b$", this is a notation that indicates exponentiation. In modern mathematics, this is typically understood as the exponentiation **function** applied to the two inputs $a$ and $b$. If we use $pow$ to denote this function, then $a^b = pow(a,b)$.

Now the whole idea of exponentiation is repeated multiplication, and that is why we usually define $pow$ such that for every real $x$ and natural $n$ we have:

> $pow(x,0) = 1$
>
> $pow(x,n+1) = pow(x,n) · x$.

To [extend this to rational and then real exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1790356/21820) is very non-trivial, and one has to **prove** the properties that the resulting $pow$ function has. One cannot just **assume** that the properties that were true for natural exponents remains true for real exponents! (See the linked post for a brief sketch of how it is done.)

In particular, after defining $x^a = pow(x,a)$ for reals $x,a$ such that $x>0$, it will still take a lot of hard work to prove the following nice properties:

> (1) $pow(x,a+b) = pow(x,a) · pow(x,b)$ for any real $x>0$ and reals $a,b$.
>
> (2) $pow(x,a·b) = pow(pow(x,a),b)$ for any real $x>0$ and reals $a,b$.

I have purposely written the properties in this manner to make it clear that it is **unjustifiable** to assume that they hold unless you have proven them. Specifically, you have attempted in your first line to use property (2) for **negative** $x$:

> (Wrong) $\color{red}{ pow(-1,2·\frac14) = pow(pow(-1,2),\frac14) }$.

And that is the **real mistake**; you have moved the factor of "$2$" from the second input of the $pow$ function to the first input, **without any justification**. It turns out that it is false, and that is why you get nonsense from the first line.

In fact, in [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2085631/21820) I gave the exact same example to show why one cannot blindly apply previously known facts about some objects to other objects, expecting them to still hold.

Answer (score 1):

We don't define rational power for negative numbers (accept odd roots, as user21820 noticed). Now, you can use branch cut (as user28120 noticed) to find root of $-1$ but if you do it so, you need to say that $(-1)^{1/2}=e^{ln(-1)\cdot1/2}$, and when you are doing it in this way, paradoxes won't appear.

Comment: You post is simply wrong. Some authors define the cube-root function to be the inverse of the cube function on the whole real line. Same for odd roots. Secondly, complex exponentiation is typically defined via a branch-cut and so there is nothing wrong with saying that the principal square root of $-1$ is $i$, where we take the branch of the natural logarithm corresponding to the argument $(-π,π]$.

Comment: Yes, you are right about odd root and branch-cut. I will edit my post.

Comment: Thanks for editing your post. Unfortunately, it still doesn't answer the question. Indeed taking the principal branch $(-1)^{1/2} = e^{\ln(-1)·1/2} = i$. So that is not the source of the error. The other answer by Anonymous is equally misleading as well...