# Extracting root of $y^3=-x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, radicals, absolute-value

Given $y^3=-x^2$ I thought the solution was $y=-x^{(2/3)}$ but as I see from the solution of my prof He wrote $y=-|x|^{(2/3)}$.

I don’t understand the absolute value since we’re extracting an odd root, what am I missing?

Comment: Check this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499287/how-exactly-is-the-function-xa-defined

Comment: @Narasimham No problem

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions are actually equivalent. Note:
$y = −x^{(2/3)}$
$\implies y = -(\sqrt[3]{x})^2$

Taking the absolute value of x doesn't change the function as we square the term anyway.

Comment: Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for introduction to $\LaTeX$. Skip the introduction of [this](https://math-on-quora.surge.sh) (because the introduction is different and does not apply to this site, rest is same).

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if $x$ is a solution, the $|x|$ is a solution as well since
$|x|^{2/3}= (|x|^2)^{1/3} = (x^2)^{1/3}=x^{2/3}$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

$$y = (-x^2)^{1/3} = (-1)^{1/3}(x^2)^{1/3}=-(x^2)^{1/3}=-x^{2/3}$$

The absolute value was brought in to make sure what was already sure, not really necessary.

Comment: Now I think you were more right and I deleted my comment :) I don't know for sure :) it's just confusing. But I think in real analysis when they write $x^a$ they just mean that this implies $x \ge 0$ And I am pretty sure that's why the professor gave this answer (he just made sure what he raises to power is non-negative).

Comment: :)  How about CAS evaluation hierarchy giving for $ (-8^2)^{(1/3.)} [\ne - 4]$ , first complex root $...(-8^2)^{(1/3.)} == (2.` + 3.4641016151377535` i)$ as True, and its conjugate  $(-8^2)^{(1/3.) }== (2.` - 3.4641016151377535` I) $ as False !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar confusion recently.

See:
[How exactly is the function $x^a$ defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499287/how-exactly-is-the-function-xa-defined)

So the key thing to realize here is this:

> **NOTE:** In real analysis when they use/write $x^a$ (for **any** $a$ real) they
> usually define it just for $x \ge 0$. This is to avoid all sorts of complications and ambiguities.

*And when I say for any $a$ real I mean the power $a$ can be positive, negative, zero, rational or irrational.*

So the way you have written your answer it implies $x \ge 0$ which is not necessarily true.

And it's in that sense (as others said) that the professor is more correct.

Important here is to realize that the **NOTE** kicks in when you're in real analysis.

Comment: So it’s a matter of definitions, i had this feeling but can’t find a real answer. Thanks for the material :)

Comment: @AndrewCarrol Yeah I think so. In high school I would give your answer by the same logic as yours. But in real analysis in a university when they write $x^a$ they imply $x \ge 0$ At least that's my current understanding.