# is $J^{-2/3}$ always a real number if J is a a real number?

Tags: real-numbers, exponentiation

Suppose $J \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is $J^{-\frac{2}{3}} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $J$ ?

I think yes, because:
$J^{-\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{J^{\frac{2}{3}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{J^2}} \in \mathbb{R}$.
Only for $J=0$, the expression is undefined.

Is that true?

Comment: Your question is circular. First *define* the object before asking where it lives.

Comment: You said "yes," and then gave an argument that the answer is "no."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{J^2}}$ is unambiguously defined for all $J\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, while $J^{-\frac 23}$ is an ambiguous expression for negative $J$.

Regarding the problem of raising a negative number to a non-integer exponent, consult [Non-integer powers of negative numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/non-integer-powers-of-negative-numbers) or [How do you compute negative numbers to fractional powers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers) or [What is $(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608023/what-is-1-frac23) etc.

Comment: "...while $J^{−{\frac{2}{3}}}$ is an ambiguous expression for negative J." I see, but for negative J, the expression is also unambigious if J is restricted to be a real number. Right?

Comment: @Simon No, I do not understand what you mean by "restricting a negative $J$ to be a real number". Anyways, $(-1)^{-\frac 23}$ is ambiguous, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. The expression $J^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ can be a real or a complex number for $J<0$. But there is only real number, right?

Comment: @Simon No, for example $(-1)^{-\frac 23}$ can either be real or complex, depending on which root you pick. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608043/998803).

Comment: "can either be real or complex" But if it is real, 1 is the only "solution", right?

Comment: @Simon In this case, yes.