# How to calculate this expression (-1)^(2/10)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

What is (-1)^(2/10)? If we do ((-1)^2)^(1/10) than it is 1 but if we do (-1)^(1/5) then it is -1. So how to solve it?

Comment: See various answers to e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317528/96384, or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/608023/96384.